# How to convert static citations into dynamic in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I had a document with references and bibliography. I've copied some parts of it to a new document on the same machine. I have noticed that the in-text references in the new document became static (not linked to the bibliography) and when adding a new reference it starts again from [1].

I tried to import the `Sources.xml` but this didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I think your question is not about programming, maybe [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) is a better site for you to migrate your question ;).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll post it there :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a MS Word feature called "**`unlink a field`**". All you have to do is to select a field (e.g. a reference) and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Alternatively one can select all (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then unlink all fields with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Comment: I want to link them. I tried CTRL+SHIFT+F9 but it didn't work with me